# Excel VBA Run-time error 9 subscrit out of range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

While closing the workbook I am getting:

`Run-time error 9 subscript out of range`

This is the VBA code:

```
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(path & filename)
  wbk.Sheets(sheetname).Range("b6").Resize(row_count, col_count).Copy
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetname).Range("b6").Resize(1, col_count).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
wbk.close
```

Can someone help me to get out from this error ?

Comment: Will this work? https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjf_KS_5fTLAhWEGY4KHfyhAF4QFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Faa264519(v%3Dvs.60).aspx&usg=AFQjCNG87H4W2-_YiVSn1741f8GpKrJdtg&sig2=Wuvs48l4692WlfxeVZZIWw

Answer (score 1):

That kind of error indicates that you are referencing to a non-existent *cell* or *range*. In your case I think that the problem is not closing but in one of these lines:

```
  wbk.Sheets(sheetname).Range("b6").Resize(row_count, col_count).Copy
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetname).Range("b6").Resize(1, col_count).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Verify that  `sheetname`, `row_count`and `col_count` contain a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using ".Resize" method in the paste?
The way I see it is that you are trying to copy range of, say 3x4 cells and paste them in 1x4 cells. That's not possible.
Try without Resizing the paste:

```
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(path & filename)
  wbk.Sheets(sheetname).Range("b6").Resize(row_count, col_count).Copy
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetname).Range("b6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
wbk.close
```

**I saw in other post a way to copy data from multiple worksheets into one:**

```
Public Sub CopyMultipleData()
    Dim ws  As Worksheet, LR1 As Long, LR2 As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Master" Then
            LR1 = Sheets("Master").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
            LR2 = ws.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
            ws.Range("A1:J" & LR2).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Master").Range("A" & LR1)
        End If
    Next ws
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I need to copy the data from multiple sheets and paste it into a single sheet.

Comment: while running the code iam getting the runtime error for only few workbooks , rest all workbooks are closing correctly.

Comment: Updated the post

Comment: And you assume you don't know how much data in each workbook?

Comment: each work book having four sheets and we don't know under which sheet we will get data and how many rows .

Comment: Try the function I've added and cycle through the sheets